# RSYNC periodically fails via SSH, broken pipe

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rsync

A post-commit script calls an `rsync` command to update files from the SVN system to a production web server, both running Ubuntu 10.04.3, `rsync` 3.1.1. The issue had been occurring with `rsync` 3.0.7 as well, upgrading to 3.1.1 was a troubleshooting step.

Regardless if files need updated or not I periodically receive:

```
Write Failed: Broken pipe
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (xxxx bytes sent so far) [sender]
```

When the pipe breaks the very verbose output 99% of the time ends at:

```
send_files(2, /some/path/to/.htaccess)
send_files(3, /some/path/to/file1.zip)
send_files(4, /some/path/to/file2.zip)
send_files(5, /some/path/to/file3.zip)
send_files(6, /some/path/to/file4.zip)
send_files(7, /some/path/to/index.php)
recv_files(22) starting
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=226): about to call exit(255)
```

`SSH` and `SCP` connections stay alive and work fine to both servers no problem. If I run the `rsync` command 10 times in a row, about 50% of the time its does it thing just fine. Transferring files from all directories exhibit this symptom, so I don’t think its a certain file type or permissions issue.

Some more outputs:

```
send_files(27, /a/different/path/verdana.ttf)
recv_files(50) starting
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=226): about to call exit(255)
```

---

```
send_files(25, /yet/another/path/unsubscribe.htm)
recv_files(162) starting
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=226): about to call exit(255)
```

Here is a sample of the command:

```
rsync -azv --delete --exclude=.svn /svn/path -e ssh user@server:/remote/path
```

Comment: ask the remote to log stuff too, eg add to your cmd: `-M --log-file=/tmp/mylog`.

Comment: @meuh, thanks. When it fails, it fails at the same spot every time as well.

`'recv_file_name' \some\file`

Comment: TCPDUMPS reveal that when things fail, both machines send TCP RST packets.

Comment: Did you try it on a different server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you see TCP RST packet whenever this fails.  This sounds similar to the issue of a firewall potentially disconnecting as mentioned on the following post, which also has a work around by re-using a hanging ssh connection.
[rsync-connection-closing-right-around-an-hour](https://serverfault.com/questions/526869/rsync-connection-closing-right-around-an-hour)

There's also an option of --timeout=[timeout value] but I think it's not as good as the hanging ssh connection solution.

Comment: It ended up being a security device which was triggering an SSH Overflow Signature, thus terminating the connection.